# Firefox: stop blinking cursor in div

Tags: html, css

On click the div below gets a blinking cursor, how can I prevents that? It is supposed to be a link not a div for text-entries. Do I need javascript?

Using Firefox:

[js fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/3MTQK/25/)

HTML

```
<div class="menupoint"></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps one of this element's ancestors have `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: `div` by default doesn't have such behavior. You are doing something else like you may have specified `contenteditable` for div. Post your actual code

Comment: clicking anywhere into the white space of the stackoverflow website , I get a blinking cursor within the layout

Comment: I click on a div like here and it blinks: [screenshot](http://i6.minus.com/jbhuYaaNBkrbZV.jpg)

Comment: @PiLHA [example code](http://jsfiddle.net/3MTQK/25/) using firefox

Comment: Blinking cursor on SO? Well, I never saw that! And I get no blinking cursor on your fiddle as well.

Comment: I realized it only happens in firefox

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Press <kbd>F7</kbd> in Firefox to turn off caret browsing mode.  This has nothing to do with your html or CSS.

Comment: @Sourabh: Perhaps you have it disabled.

Comment: No, I pressed F7, and it did enable. I tried navigating with TAB but no blinking cursor.

Answer (score -1):

you can use CSS to change to cursor on your `div`

kindly check this : [CSS cursor Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: the mouse cursor is not the problem, but after clicking it blinks, expecting text input